# Why can I login through this form with a browser, but not LWP?

Tags: html, perl, forms, post, lwp

I was trying to login into a website which uses this form with three inputs to authenticate.

```
<form action="/login.html" method="post">
<div class="loginlabel1 aright">ID / Email: </div>
<div class="bsearchfield">
<input type="text" name="profid" class="inputBx" size="15" value="" />
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="loginlabel1 aright">Password: </div>
<div class="bsearchfield">
<input type="password" name="password" class="inputBx" size="15" value="" />
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="loginbutton1">
<input name="login"type="image" src="images/logi.gif" align="right" border="0" />
</div>
</form>
```

If I login through browser, a successful login redirects me to http://www.example.com/myhome.html.

But the following script is not logging me in and returns the same `login.html` page. Did I miss something? I am not getting any error message. Did I post successfully?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use LWP 5.64;
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new || die " Failed LWP USER AGENT : $!";
$ENV{HTTP_proxy} = "http://proxy:port";
$browser->env_proxy;
$browser->cookie_jar({});
my @Header    = (
                    'User-Agent'      => 'Mozilla/4.76 [en] (Win98; U)',
                    'Accept'          => 'image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg,image/pjpeg, image/png, */*',
                    'Accept-Charset'  => 'iso-8859-1,*,utf-8',
                    'Accept-Language' => 'en-US',
              );

push @{$browser->requests_redirectable}, 'POST';
$response = $browser->post(
    "http://www.example.com/login.html",
    [
        'profid'   => 'username',
        'password' => 'password'
    ],@Header
);

$response->is_success or die "Failed to post: ", $response->status_line;
print "Successfully posted username and password.\n" if $response->is_fresh;

#printf("%s",$response->content);
printf("%s\n", $response->status_line);
printf("%s",   $response->header("Accept-Ranges"));
printf("%s",   $response->header("Age"));
printf("%s",   $response->header("ETag"));
printf("%s",   $response->header("Location"));
printf("%s",   $response->header("Proxy-Authenticate"));
printf("%s",   $response->header("Retry-After"));
printf("%s",   $response->header("Server"));
printf("%s",   $response->header("Vary"));
printf("%s",   $response->header("WWW-Authenticate"));
delete $ENV{HTTP_PROXY};
```

Comment: perhaps you can try to diagnose the problem. Are you getting a redirect response code or a 200 OK or something else?

Comment: No..It is returning me the same login page. No error code

Comment: what is your response code? is it 200 OK? what are the full headers?

Comment: Yes..It gives me 200 OK as response.And only prints response header field - server = Apache

Answer (score 2):

Your submit button is an image. When clicking on an input of type image, a browser sends the pixel coordinates where you clicked to the CGI. In your form, a browser would send `login.x` and `login.y` along with `profid` and `password`.

BTW, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is a great tool for debugging CGI.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes they require correct accept-encoding and/or referer headers. I'd also try user-agent header, to be sure.

Comment: +1 This is the accurate way to debug this kind of problem. Comparing requests with a network sniffer, such as Wireshark, also helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend [LiveHTTPHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) for Firefox.  You turn it on, then submit your form and it shows exactly what was GET or POST'd to the site, including all headers, params, and cookies and then shows all of the responses from the server including set cookies, headers, and redirects.

There could be javascript on the page creating additional params that you are not seeing when you just look at the form, the image coords as PacoRG above stated, or it may be requiring that you accept a cookie first and sent that with the login.

LiveHTTPHeaders also lets you modify the headers and "replay" - this lets you modify what is sent to the server (any headers, cookies, params, etc) to help determine what is actually required by the server to login.

Also, I believe that LWP by default automatically follows redirects, so the page may actually be redirecting and you are not seeing it (I believe the "simple_request" function does not follow redirs.)

In the LWP response, you can walk backwards through any redirects like so:

```
my $prev_res = $res->previous();
while ( $prev_res ) {
    print $prev_res->status_line . "\n";
    $prev_res = $prev_res->previous();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You're not submitting the name of the submit button which is clicked; I suspect the code at the other end is checking for the presence of that variable in the request to see if the form has been submitted or not.

As PacoRG points out, the submit button is an image; as such, submitting by clicking that button  in a browser would submit fields named "login.x" and "login.y", along with "login".

A good way to avoid problems like this is to use [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize) to do a lot of the work for you, for instance:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->get('http://www.example.com/login.html');
$mech-submit_form(
    with_fields => {
        profid => $username,
        password => $password,
    },
);
```

The above would request the login page, find the appropriate form, and submit it.

Also, as others have said, if requests from your script are handled differently to requests from your browser, the best way to debug is to grab the full HTTP request that both send, and look for pertinent differences.  For the browser, you can use an extension like Firefox's LiveHTTPHeaders or Tamper Data plugins, or use something like Wireshark to capture the request as it's sent.  For the script, you can easily have it output the request being sent.

For instance, for a script using LWP::UserAgent or WWW::Mechanize (which subclasses LWP::UserAgent), you can add:

```
$mech->add_handler("request_send", sub { shift->dump; return });
$mech->add_handler("response_done", sub { shift->dump; return });
```

This will dump the raw request sent, along with the raw response from the server.  (Change `$mech` to whatever var your LWP::UserAgent / WWW::Mechanize object is in - `$browser` in your example.)